# How to select Duplicate values that is mapped in Junction table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates

I have created Employee, Department and EmpDept Table.

Here EmpDept table is Junction Table.

```
EmpDept(Junction Table)

EmpID           DeptID

101         502

103         501

102         504

104         502

105         502

106         505

107         507

108         509
```

Here, the "**EmpId**" is Referenced from "**Employee**" table and "**EmpId**" is a Primary key and "**DeptId**" is ***not*** referenced from "**Department**" table.

```
 Employee

EmpID   EmpName     

    101 Shama

    103 Varun   

    102 Joesph

    104 Ram

    105 Ravi

    106 Deva

    107 Mukund
```

Here, **EmpId is Primary Key**.

```
Department

DeptName    DeptID

x       501

        502

J       503

R       504

A       505

D       506

M       507

z       508

C       509
```

Now, I have to get Duplicate values that have been there in **EmpDept** table and display corresponding **EmpName** which has the same name.

Comment: Your `EmpDept ` junction table should have its own primary key and 2x foreign keys: one for `Employee` table and one for `Department` table.

Comment: The typical use for a junction table is to maintain a many-to-many relationship; for instance an employee can be assigned many departments and a department can have many employees. Given that, what do you mean by duplicate values in EmpDept? And @VidmantasBlazevicius is correct. That table should have it's own primary key. Could you show us the query or queries you've tried, the results you got, and a sample of the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @DepIDTemp int
set @DepIDTemp=(select EmpDept.DepartmentId
from EmpDept
group by EmpDept.DepartmentId
 having count(EmpDept.DepartmentId)>1) 
 Select DEPARTMENT.DepartmentId, DepartmentName,EMPLOYEE.EmployeeName,EMPLOYEE.EmployeeId from
 DEPARTMENT
 join EmpDept on EmpDept.DEPARTMENTID=DEPARTMENT.DepartmentId
 join EMPLOYEE on EmpDept.EMPLOYEEID=EMPLOYEE.EmployeeId
 where DEPARTMENT.DepartmentId=@DepIDTemp;
```

Here, is my Solution.